# Javascript: substring time complexity

Tags: javascript, string, substring

What is time complexity of javascript's substring method?

I think implementation of this method may be same as Java but for Java now substring has `O(N)` complexity from Java7 onwards and `O(1)` for pre-Java7.

Comment: have you done any effort to find it?

Comment: I doubt substring can have O(1) complexity considering strings can vastly vary in length. I'm imagining O(n) at best, but I don't know f about Java

Comment: In my understanding it should be `O(N)` as string internally is an array of characters

Comment: _"I think implementation of this method may be same as Java"_ -> [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: I imagine if would be O(n). Interestingly you can do your own analysis of the algorithms time complexity by feeding in your own strings

Comment: @SagarV This question does not seems to be asked on stackoverflow before and hence qualifies to be asked here. And believe me I did my research before asking the simple question. If for you research means looking into source code and writing code to find complexity then no.

Comment: @naomik The best substring algorithm is actually O(n/m) where m is the length of the substring (needle). Google Boyer-Moore algorithm.

Comment: @slebetman Are you confusing string search with substring?

Comment: @Bergi Ah yes. Sorry. In which case best case substring should be O(1). Why should it be anything else unless you implement strings as linked lists (or ropes)

Comment: @slebetman yes, exactly that: not all strings are necessarily represented as contiguous slices of memory, e.g. the results of concatenations. Also, keeping only references around is a horror for garbage collection.

Comment: Looks like it is O(n) because a new memory is allocated for each substring operation.